# bluetooth 5.0 multicast on android

Tags: bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Does the bluetooth 5.0 support multicast (Simplification of multi-link)?
I need to be connected (transmit) to two devices at the same time via bluetooth, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, since BT 3.1 it is possible to multicast to 2 devices, but sadly not more than that.

Comment: Can you please tell what is the actual [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: 'I need to be connected (transmit) to two devices at the same time via bluetooth, is it possible?' -> 'since BT 3.1 it is possible to multicast to 2 devices' . Question is answered quite directly.